# Behavior of steps_per_epoch and validation_steps in Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a little bit confused on the behavior of `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` in the fit function. More particularly, if I set `steps_per_epoch` to be smaller than `total_records/batch_size`, would it be that a) the model only trains on the same subset of training data for every epoch or b) the model will use different training data for each epoch and will eventually cover all the training data?

The same question for `validation_steps`.

For example, if I have 10000 rows for training with a batch size of 10 and `steps_per_epoch` set to 10, would the model be training only on the first 100 rows for all the epochs or it will be training on different 100 rows in each epoch and go through all the rows after 100 epochs?

I tried to search for it in the documentation and online but have not find any mention of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#fit) state that using the parameter `shuffle` in `model.fit(...)` has no effect when using a generator and when `steps_per_epoch` is *not* `None`, it is essentially up to your data generator to shuffle the rows everytime it is called otherwise you will always get the same results. Check for example, how the [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator?version=nightly#flow_from_directory) works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 2

flowers = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)

img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=20)

ds = img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

for x, y in ds:
  print(x.shape, y)
  break
```

Using `shuffle=True` results in different values everytime, whereas `shuffle=False` always returns the same values.

Comment: I think I get it. My understanding is if `ds.take(1)` returns different data on each call, the `fit` function will use different data. Is my understanding correct? @AloneTogether

Comment: @Woody yes, your understanding is correct when `shuffle=True`, otherwise you the output will always be deterministic.